# How to change table's cell color created from JSON

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I created an HTML table from JSON. The table is university semester map that includes student's ID, year, term and courses required to graduate. I have successful created the table but I want the courses' cell's color depends on courses status. For example, if the student has taken CSCI 135, that cell color should be green. If the course is in progress, the cell color should be yellow. If it needs to be taken, the cell should be red.

My query to get all the courses is

```
$getCourses = "SELECT * FROM student_majors WHERE student_id = $studID;";
```

query for courses status

```
$status = "SELECT * FROM course_status WHERE student_id = $studID;";
```

the function I used to create the table is following

```
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
        var myCourses = <?php echo $test1; ?> ;
        var col = [] ;
        var col2 = ["Year","Term","Requirement","","","","","Core","","Credits"] ;
        for (var i = 0; i < myCourses.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myCourses[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                

        for (var i = 0; i < col2.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");     
            th.innerHTML = col2[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < myCourses.length; i++) {
            tr = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myCourses[i][col[j]];
            }
        }
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
```

I've tried using jquery, js functions to change cell's color based on status of the course but none of those work.

```
function f_color(){
            if (document.getElementByTagName('td').value = 'CSCI135') {
                document.getElementByTagName('td').style.background="yellow";
            }
        }
         for (var k = 0; k< col.length; k++){
                $("#output td:contains(CSCI135)").attr("style","background-color:green");
                $("#output td:contains(CSCI135)").attr("style","background-color:red");
            }
```

Comment: From where you will get the status?

Comment: Since this is a JavaScript question, providing the JS code would be more helpful, rather than `<?php echo $test1; ?>`.This would allow others to reproduce your problem more easily.

Comment: $test 1 is just json_encode($resultset,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT). I provided most of my js code already. All other codes are from php, html and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote sample snippet to set background color while preparing table itself. You can refer both the ways to set the background color and try to implement it in your scenario.

```js
var myCourses = [{
   "Year": 2018,
   "Term": 'A',
   "Requirement": 'Course',
   "Core": 'CSCI135',
   "Credits": 120
},
{
   "Year": 2019,
   "Term": 'A',
   "Requirement": 'Course',
   "Core": 'CSCI136',
   "Credits": 130
},
{
   "Year": 2019,
   "Term": 'A',
   "Requirement": 'Course',
   "Core": 'CSCI200',
   "Credits": 100
},
{
   "Year": 2019,
   "Term": 'A',
   "Requirement": 'Course',
   "Core": 'CSCI123',
   "Credits": 140
},
{
   "Year": 2019,
   "Term": 'A',
   "Requirement": 'Course',
   "Core": 'abc',
   "Credits": 150
}
];
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
        var col = [] ;
        var col2 = ["Year","Term","Requirement","Core","Credits"] ;
        for (var i = 0; i < myCourses.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myCourses[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                

        for (var i = 0; i < col2.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");     
            th.innerHTML = col2[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < myCourses.length; i++) {
            tr = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myCourses[i][col[j]];
                /* 1st Way*/
                if(col[j] == 'Credits'){
                   if(myCourses[i][col[j]] > 130 ){
                    tabCell.style.background = 'green'; 
                   }
                   else if(myCourses[i][col[j]] < 130 ){
                    tabCell.style.background = 'red'; 
                   }
                   else {
                    tabCell.style.background = 'yellow'; 
                   }
                }
                /*2nd Way */
                if(col[j] == 'Core'){
                   if(myCourses[i][col[j]] == 'CSCI135' ){
                    tabCell.className = 'success'; 
                   }
                   else if(myCourses[i][col[j]] == 'CSCI123' ){
                    tabCell.className = 'completed'; 
                   }
                   else {
                    tabCell.className = 'inprocess'; 
                   }
                }
            }
        }
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
    
  CreateTableFromJSON();
```

```css
.success{
   background: green;
}

.completed{
   background: red;
}

.inprocess{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="showData"></div>
```

Comment: It is kind of working. My last question is how to vertify the courses status of a particular student. I will probably spend entire day on that tomottow. Hopefully you can point me to the right direction

Comment: @cheunology add sample JSON structure you are using. So that I can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help I really appreciate it,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55719856/changing-jsons-html-tables-cell-color-based-on-status

Comment: @cheunology, I check that code. why you are using php echo and JSON decode in for loop.. instead of that you can take values into variables and use those variables

Comment: @cheunology what is that in_array refers to array or function ?

Comment: I actually figured it out myself posted the answer below. Let me know if there could be any improvement. That in_array is a php function i wanted to use since i wasnt too familiar with javascript

Comment: @cheunology, I modified you're answer. You can review the changes.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Would you know how to implement drag and drop into the table?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (var i = 0; i < myCourses.length; i++) {
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);  // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var j = 0; j < col2.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            var done_course = <?php echo json_encode($done_course); ?> ;
            var pending_course = <?php echo json_encode($pending_course); ?> ;
            var progress_course = <?php echo json_encode($progress_course); ?> ;
            tabCell.innerHTML = myCourses[i][col[j]];     
              if (done_course.includes(myCourses[i][col[j]])) {
                tabCell.className = 'success'; 
              } else if (pending_course.includes(myCourses[i][col[j]])) {
                tabCell.className = 'completed'; }
                  else {
                    tabCell.className = 'inprocess'; }
        }
    }
```