# Changing JSON's HTML table's cell color based on status

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, json

I have a HTML table created by JSON. The table is a college semaster's map, it lists all the required courses for your major. I want the courses' cell color depends on the status. For example, green means course is completed, yellow means in progress and red means need to be taken.  below is the columns, and createtablefromJSON function

```
var col2 = ["year","term","major1","major2","major3","major4","major5","core1","Core2","Credits"] ;

function CreateTableFromJSON() {
        var myCourses = <?php echo $test1; ?> ;
        var col = [] ;// EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
        var col2 = ["year","term","major1","major2","major3","major4","major5","core1","Core2","Credits"] ;
        for (var i = 0; i < myCourses.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myCourses[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }
        var table = document.createElement("table");        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.
        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.
        for (var i = 0; i < col2.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col2[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }
```

My question is how to change cell's color based on status of the course

```
for (var i = 0; i < myCourses.length; i++) {
          tr = table.insertRow(-1);  // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
            for (var j = 0; j < col2.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myCourses[i][col[j]];     
                   if (<?php in_array ?> (myCourses[i][col[j]] <?php  echo ",". json_encode($done_course) ?> )  {
                                  <?php if ($done) { ?> tabCell.className = 'success'; <?php } ?>  }

                   if (<?php in_array ?> (myCourses[i][col[j]] <?php echo ",". json_encode($pending_course) ?> )  {
                                  <?php if ($pending) { ?> tabCell.className = 'pending'; <?php } ?>  }
                          }
                   if (<?php in_array ?> (myCourses[i][col[j]] <?php echo ",". json_encode($progess_course) ?> )  {
                                  <?php if ($progess) { ?> tabCell.className = 'inprocess'; <?php } ?>  }
                          }
                      }     
                  }
              }
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
```

Comment: If javascript is also to check array functions that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert php array to js array. Then use .includes() function to check

```
 for (var i = 0; i < myCourses.length; i++) {
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);  // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var j = 0; j < col2.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            var done_course = <?php echo json_encode($done_course); ?> ;
            var pending_course = <?php echo json_encode($pending_course); ?> ;
            var progress_course = <?php echo json_encode($progress_course); ?> ;
            tabCell.innerHTML = myCourses[i][col[j]];     
              if (done_course.includes(myCourses[i][col[j]])) {
                tabCell.className = 'success'; 
              } else if (pending_course.includes(myCourses[i][col[j]])) {
                tabCell.className = 'completed'; }
                  else {
                    tabCell.className = 'inprocess'; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check your in array like this,

`indexOf()`

```
if (myCourses[i][col[j]] == "<?php echo $done_course; ?>")  {
  <?php if ($done) { ?> tabCell.className = 'success'; <?php } ?>
}
else if (myCourses[i][col[j]] == "<?php echo $pending_course; ?>")  {
  <?php if ($pending) { ?> tabCell.className = 'pending'; <?php } ?>  }
}
else {
  <?php if ($progess) { ?> tabCell.className = 'inprocess'; <?php } ?>  }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing after this code?

Comment: My table literally disappeared. Should I there be a better for loop beofre?

Comment: remove that while loop and check

Comment: remove this `while(col2[j]<= col.length){` while loop it wil not allow the condition inside